# Xcode 4 Interface Builder Slow Performance

Tags: iphone, xcode

Has anybody noticed that Interface Builder on the latest Xcode 4 is significantly slower than Xcode 3? Every time I had to restart the machine as soon as I'm done with the Interface Builder because the Xcode editor responsiveness was just unbearable.

I'm considering to migrate my XIBs to Objective-C code if I can't fix it. My machine is a 2.4 Duo with 2GB RAM, and the XIB file was just a simple UIView. Am I the only one experiencing it?

Comment: Please file a bug report and then switch to Xcode 3 or just its Interface Builder in the meantime! You as developer shouldn't work around your IDE just because its a beta release.

Comment: What are you talking about? Xcode 4 has been a stable release.

Comment: What beta release? Xcode is officially released!

Comment: I know that is has been officially released, it feels just like beta software. And Xcode 4 might be anything but not a "stable" release.

Comment: Xcode is a migration of released and unstable software. Hope Apple fix those performance problems asap.

Comment: The exact words would be.. Wait for XCode4.1

Comment: you will be able regain some umph by installing 4GB - projects/setups vary a lot, but 2GB is very low for the majority of Xc4 users/setups. it's a cheap upgrade. i have 4GB one of my machines, and manually balance memory *too* often when using it. (that's not to say that it will solve all your problems...)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this question a million times so that Apple would get the point and fix this ASAP. How is that when you upgrade the performance of the software is considerably worse? This issue has bummed me out totally.

Comment: I simply migrated anything in Interface Builder to Objective C code......

Comment: Migrating to Objective C is definitely *not* a solution. IB is an amazing tool if you know how to use it and speeds up the development process tremendously. This new version is too slow without any apparent reason, though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Xcode 4 is **extremely** slow on a 2.26GHz Intel Core 2 Duo MacBook, to the point of being unusable for interface-related work.

When the Interface Builder pane is opened, performance becomes glacial with even the most basic interface operations. The most minor operations (e.g. selecting an Interface Builder element, and moving it) involve a one-second delay before the object moves, then a further delay while the various Inspector values update. Activity Monitor spikes, and stays spiked for several seconds.

Using any other app (e.g. Safari) becomes an exercise in frustration, involving lengthy (> 30 second) periods with the spinning beach ball of death.

Even with all other apps killed off, Xcode 4 exhibits major problems. IMO, the current version is not production-level software, and is borderline broken.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: `spinning beach ball of death` -- Didn't know it was called like this. Laughed for 2 minutes :))

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4 needs much more resources from your machine. I have those problems, too.

I recommend you to close all processes you don't need and close heavy applications like browsers, Adobe Products, Skype, Windows Live Messenger, Time Machine, etc. then you'll have a little bit more performance in Xcode. Otherwise you may buy more RAM for your Mac...

Comment: Using an SSD also does wonders.

Comment: I'm using an SSD as well, and moved my project to the SSD.  Still horrible unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to bring this thread back to life but i may found a way to release the memory used by the interface builder built in xcode4. I found out that, if you close just the open xib file in Xcode4 by pressing ^ CMD W, or go to file -> close document xy. At the moment when the xib document got closed. The memory is released and ready to use. Maybe it will help al little bit. I doesn't need to restart my mac now ;)